# Integration with respect to the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure associated with floor function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

For two different measures, I am trying to identify $L^1(\mu)$(the set of integrable functions, i.e. $\{f:\int \lvert f\rvert du<\infty\}$, and trying to compute $\int fd\mu$ for $f\in L^1(\mu)$.

- on $\mathbb R, \mu=\mu_F$, the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure with $F(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$.

**Attempts**

- I know that the unique measure derived from the floor function would measure the number of integers between the end points, or in the set. But I'm not sure how to build on that to use to calculate the integral for a general $f$, or what would make a function integrable.

**Update**: $$\int 1_{E}(x)d\mu(x)=\mu(E)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}1_E(n)$$
should be true for any characteristic function. And for this integral to be finite, in any Borel set $E$, there should only be finite number of integers in the set. But I'm not sure how to bootsrap up from this point to simple functions, and then functions in general.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider the set $\{x:\lvert f(x)\rvert>0\}$

Comment: @pilotmath thanks for the comment, it helped solving the first part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your update you have correctly identified that $\mu=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta_k$.

Take a simple function $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \chi_{A_i}(x)$ such that $\mu(A_i)<\infty$ for all $i$. Its integral is defined as
$$
\int f\,d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \mu(A_i)
= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \delta_k(A_i)
= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \delta_k(A_i)
= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \chi(A_i)(k)
= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f(k) .
$$

If now $f$ is a non-negative Borel function and $(f_n)$ are simple functions converging monotonically to $f$, you have
$$
\int f\,d\mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f_n(k)
= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f(k)
$$
by monotone convergence.
Such a non-negative function is integrable iff $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f(k) < \infty$.

Finally, if $f=f^+-f^-$ is a generic Borel function, it belongs to $L^1(\mu)$ if and only if $\int f^\pm\,d\mu < \infty$ and in such case you have
$$
\int f\,d\mu = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f^+(k) - \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f^-(k)
= \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} f(k) .
$$
So $f\in L^1(\mu)$ iff
$$
\int |f|\,d\mu = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} |f(k)| < \infty .
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was stuck on switching of the summations on the simple functions, but you can do that since they are all non-negative. One thing, does any $f$ that is integrable take value $0$ on any non-integer input?

Comment: @user282639 No, they can take arbitrary values in $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$. And two functions are in the same equivalence class w.r.t. $\mu$ iff they coincide on the integers.

Comment: ah I could visualize these sets as equivalence classes then!

Comment: Functions in $L^p$ are always equivalence classes of functions which differ on sets of measure $0$, otherwise the distance would not be positive definite. You can extend this concept to sets, but you need to be clear with your readers. There's also less motivation to do so, in that we do not require the measureable sets to be a metric space (nb: the equivalence classes of sets are a metric space with $d(A, B) = \mu(A \Delta B)$ where $\Delta$ is the symmetric difference, but this is not usually of use).